# How to add Search type functionality in Edit text and List view

Tags: android, search, custom-lists

I am having a list view and an edit text. When i write on Edit text i want to display my list view Starting with those alphabets. I am adding a custom adapter to My list view.

here is my Edit text addTextChangedListener

```
getFriendsName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            friends_available.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and here is my List view over which i am setting a custom adapter

```
  adapter = new GroupAvailableFriendsToAddAdapter((BaseActivity) getActivity(),
                connectionsList);
        friends_available.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is my Adapter class

```
public class GroupAvailableFriendsToAddAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemsAllPost> {

private BaseActivity _context;
private ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private ItemsAllPost postData;
private String result;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int count;
private TextView textView;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;



public GroupAvailableFriendsToAddAdapter(BaseActivity activity,
        ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> connectionsList) {
    super(activity, R.layout.group_avialable_friends_list_adapter, connectionsList);
    _context = activity;
    data = connectionsList;
    count=connectionsList.size();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ItemsAllPost items = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_avialable_friends_list_adapter,
                null);
    }
    TextView FriendsName = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.group_available_friendNameTV);
    CircularImageView image_profile = (CircularImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.group_available_friendImgCI);
    FriendsName.setText(items.user_first_name);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(items.profile_image,
            image_profile);


    return view;
}
```

}

problem is initially list view is showing the List but when i enter a text it simply hides even the entered text matches the List view Items  and when i erase the text from Edit text list view shows back.

what i am doing wrong?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: paste code of your getfilter() method plz

Comment: i think getfilter is inbuilt method of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ali's method would require you to set the adapter each time with a new search text. Rather you could just implement a Filterable class and notify the adapter regarding a change in data after every search. Change you adapter to the below. It should work fine!

```
public class GroupAvailableFriendsToAddAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemsAllPost> implements Filterable{
//create a new temporary list
private ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> data, tempListData;

public GroupAvailableFriendsToAddAdapter(BaseActivity activity, ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> connectionsList) {
    super(activity, R.layout.group_avialable_friends_list_adapter, connectionsList);
    data = connectionsList;
    **tempListData** = connectionsList; //make this list point to your original list
}

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return **tempListData** .size(); // make the count point to this tempList as the list size would vary with every search text
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemsAllPost items = **tempListData** .get(position); // reference data using this tempList
    FriendsName.setText(items.user_first_name);
    return view;
}

@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                final List<ItemsAllPost> tempFliteredDataList = new ArrayList<ItemsAllPost();
                // We implement here the filter logic
                if (constraint == null || constraint.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    results.values = data;
                } else {
                    // We perform filtering operation
                    String constrainString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (ItemsAllPost post: data) {
                        if (post.user_first_name.toLowerCase().contains(constrainString)) {
                            tempFliteredDataList.add(post);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = tempFliteredDataList ;
                }
                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results.values!=null){
                    **tempListData** = (ArrayList<ItemsAllPost>) results.values; // returns the filtered list based on the search
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with one more issue that i am getting now

Comment: I'll try, post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following code and it worked for me as expected :

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           int textlength = cs.length();
           ArrayList<ContactStock> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<ContactStock>();
           for(ContactStock c: arraylist){
              if (textlength <= c.getName().length()) {
                 if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempArrayList.add(c);
                 }
              }
           }
           mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(activity, tempArrayList);
           lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     }
```

You can follow [this tutorial](http://android-helper.blogspot.se/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html) in order to have more detail information as well as sample code.