# Issue with adding addTextChangedListener in adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement a search function in my application. I have used an adapter to because I want to display 2 textviews in listview and listview should be clickable (I don;t think it's possible to do without an adapter).

My problem is I can't use `addTextChangedListener` in the adapter class. it gives exception (It worked in my activity class).

**search activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.search_results_activity);

new SearchMenuAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), this).execute();

listtv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.product_lv);

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

}

@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

```
try {

    final List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> menudescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
        final JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

        if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("5")
                && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("6")
                && (object.getString("Visible")).equals("true")) {
            Log.i("descriptionsBev ", object.getString("Description"));
            descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
            Log.i("MenuDescription ",
                    object.getString("MenuDescription"));
            menudescriptions
                    .add(object.getString("MenuDescription"));

        }

        adapter = new CustomListSearch(
                getApplicationContext(), descriptions,
                menudescriptions);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

**CustomListSearch.java**

```
    public class CustomListSearch extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private final List<String> descriptions;
    private List<String>filteredData = null;
    private final List<String> menudescriptions;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public CustomListSearch(Context c, List<String> data,
            List<String> menudescriptions) {
        this.context = c;
        this.filteredData = data ;
        this.descriptions = data;
        this.menudescriptions = menudescriptions;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvMenudescriptions;
        private TextView tvDescriptions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.tvDescriptions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.tvMenudescriptions = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_description);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvDescriptions.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        holder.tvMenudescriptions.setText(menudescriptions.get(position));

        LinearLayout itemlist = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_lv);
        itemlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Still under constructions...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = descriptions;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

I was following below answer and worked this out

[Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Comment: I'm a bit confused there, how many editText do you actually have?

Comment: I have 1 edit text view but i have t textviews

Comment: so I believe you should set the textwatcher somewhere else, not in the adapter class, the adapter doesn't have to know about where the search is coming from and etc... it's only job is to display the result data

Comment: okay thakns for that info, I have spent lot of time trying that. Can you help me to use textwatcher in search activity or someother palce?

Comment: Ok sure, I see that you make a call to adapter.getFilter(), where's the part of the code responsible for the filtering?

Comment: in my OnTaskComplete I have descriptions, it carries all the items to be filtered.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the current flow is: you download a full list of objects first, and then you want to filter these results based on what the user types, am I right? (Sorry for asking that many questions, but it's important to understand the full context)

Comment: No problem with that, I'm getting all the items from json response and then I'm loading all the item names to descriptions list array. Then loading it to an adapter.

Comment: Ok so here's what I'd probably do: keep a reference to your edittext and the adapter in the activity, and attach the textwatcher to the edittext inside onCreate. Once you're finished loading all the results from the server, put them all into the adapter and make the adapter implements filterable. Then when the text has changed, you can call yourAdapter.getFilter().performFiltering(textOfYourSearch).

Comment: I have done some changes. Now I can type in the code but it doesn't filter properly. If I update the code will u be able to check?