# Android ListView Filter is changing List Item State

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have created a listview and each row has a checkbox. Initially some check boxes are checked and some are not. On top the listview there is a Edittext, when I enter values in edittext list shows only filtered values. By the way I have implemeted Filterable interface. Problem I am facing is I am getting filtered result after entering some value in edit text with checkbox state is unevenly changed. I mean Checked check box for a row is showing as unchecked after filtering and vice-versa.

## My ListView Adapter code is as follows

```
    public class AllUsersListAdapter implements ListAdapter, Filterable {

        public List<HEADER> allUsers;
        public List<HEADER>filteredUsers;
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        private Filter mFilter;
        private DataSetObservable mDataSetObservable = new DataSetObservable();

        public AllUsersListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<HEADER> allUsers) {
            this.filteredUsers = this.allUsers =  allUsers;
            this.context = context;
            layoutResourceId = resource;
        }


        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.registerObserver(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            mDataSetObservable.unregisterObserver(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return filteredUsers.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HEADER getItem(int position) {
            return filteredUsers.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.userName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userName);
                holder.desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userDesc);
                    holder.rowCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);
                    holder.rowCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                HEADER header = getItem(position);
                if(CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.contains(header))
                {
                    holder.rowCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                }
                    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
                holder.rowCheckBox.setTag(allUsers.get(position));
                    holder.rowCheckBox
                            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                             boolean isChecked) {
                                    HEADER element = (HEADER) finalHolder.rowCheckBox
                                            .getTag();
                                    if (isChecked) {
                                       CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.remove(element);
                                        CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.add(element);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.remove(element);
                                        CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.add(element);
                                    }
                                }
                            });;
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            HEADER header = getItem(position);
            holder.userName.setText(header.getNAME());
            holder.desc.setText(header.getFRONTEND_ID());
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (mFilter == null) {
                mFilter = new ContactFilter();
            }
            return mFilter;
        }

        private class ContactFilter extends Filter {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filterResults.values = allUsers;
                    filterResults.count = allUsers.size();
                } else {
                    final String lastToken = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    final int count = allUsers.size();
                    final List<HEADER> list = new ArrayList<HEADER>();
                    HEADER header;

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        header = allUsers.get(i);
                        if (header.getNAME().toLowerCase().startsWith(lastToken)) {
                            list.add(header);
                        }
                    }

                    filterResults.values = list;
                    filterResults.count = list.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredUsers = (List<HEADER>)results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        }

        public void clearSelectedUsersList() {
            if (allUsers != null) allUsers.clear();
        }

        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            mDataSetObservable.notifyChanged();
        }

        public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
            mDataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated();
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView userName;
            TextView desc;
            ImageButton cancel_image_button;
            CheckBox rowCheckBox;
        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/1576416

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Comment: Don't down vote just because you have enough reputation. Try to understand the problem. Problem is not about filtering , problem here is item state not preserving after filteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.userName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        holder.desc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userDesc);
            holder.rowCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);
            holder.rowCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //HEADER header = getItem(position);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    HEADER header = getItem(position);

 if(CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.contains(header))
        {
            holder.rowCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.rowCheckBox.setTag(allUsers.get(position));
            holder.rowCheckBox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {
                            HEADER element = (HEADER) holder.rowCheckBox
                                    .getTag();
                            if (isChecked) {
                               CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.remove(element);
                                CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.add(element);
                            }
                            else {
                                CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.remove(element);
                                CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.add(element);
                            }
                        }
                    });;
    holder.userName.setText(header.getNAME());
    holder.desc.setText(header.getFRONTEND_ID());
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## I found solution for my problem. Following change actually solves the problem.

```
 holder.rowCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v;
                HEADER element = (HEADER) cb.getTag();
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                            CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.remove(element);
                            CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.add(element);
                        }
                        else {
                            CreateGroupHelperClass.selectedUsers.remove(element);
                            CreateGroupHelperClass.unSelectedUsers.add(element);
                        }
            }
        });
```

Instead of OnCheckedChangeListener() I used View.OnClickListener() and that solved my problem.

Comment: Does this solve your problem with the filtering? I discovered the same issue, using an ArrayAdapter with its default Filter implementation. If you change the  filter text on the adapter, it's not very smart about keeping the checked states - the impl basically tries to find the same ID nearby, if it can't find it, it removed the checked state. Seems like I will have to detect dataset change myself and reapply the checked if an item comes back into the listview.

Comment: And that's after subclassing ArrayAdapter to provide `setHasStableIds`, otherwise the listview will just leave the view at the same positions checked - although they are totally different items