# Listview Search is working only for 1st letter from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have written following code for search in listview:

```
  edtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

It is search for only 1st letter and it is not showing the search keyword data.

How can i search it for whole string and shows only related search data from adapter?

Comment: Try this `itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtsearch.getText().toString());`

Comment: No. Still it search for 1st character only.

Comment: Is it a custom Adapter?

Comment: yes. it is custom adapter

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android