# Search Functionality to ListView flags - Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview

I have been trying to implement a simple search to a listView which i have been able to populate using Volley but all to no avail  till date.
It keeps flagging this **Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()**

I have also tried other peoples question which relates to this same search issue but none seems to work for me so i had no choice than to post mine here.
Below is my Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ListView mList;
   private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
   EditText inputSearch;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


           adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
           mList.setAdapter(adapter);

             fetchMovie(); 
             // A method i declared in the program to load data from server with  volley library which works fine

        //SEARCH TEXTCHANGE
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                   // When user changed the Text
                  MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                //FLAGS Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()' here
                }

             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             }
          });




    }



}
```

Here is the CustomListAdapter code which populates my listView well

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private List<Movie> movieItems;
        private String[] bgColors;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();


         public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
             this.activity = activity;
             this.movieItems = movieItems;
             bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
         }
         @Override
         public int getCount() {
                return movieItems.size();
         }

         @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
             return movieItems.get(location);
         }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
               return position;
            }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
              inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image, null);

             if (imageLoader == null)
              imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

             TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

            // getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

            // thumbnail image
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

            // title
            title.setText(m.getTitle());

            // rating
             rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

            // genre
            String genreStr = "";
            for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
              genreStr += str + ", ";
              }
            genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                 genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
             genre.setText(genreStr);

            // release year
             year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

             String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
            serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));




            return convertView;
     }
}
```

Would appreciate any one who can assist me on what exactly i am not doing right as this little issue has been frustrating my whole project for days now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Cannot Resolve Method" getFilter()'`. Because [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) clas doesn’t have method `getFilter()`. But [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) has `getFilter()` method.

You can refer [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android) or [How could i filter the listview using baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android) stackoverflow post to `implement filter` on `BaseAdapter class` or if possible you can switch from `BaseAdapter` to `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: I have never been this close to the solution of this simple yet complex search feature. 
Adding your reference link codes to my codes made the program to stop flagging on **getFilter()**  but when i trying searching, nothing happens as the content in the ListView never changes when i type on the EditView

Comment: I added the following to CustomListAdaptor

public Filter **getFilter()**{
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class **ItemFilter** extends Filter {
        

    }



But the search did not populate the list. 
Can u still tell me what i am missing here ?

Comment: is their a way i can update the Question-code i posted so that i can update the code inside the question.

I dont seem to find a way to post my code here not edit my question to update the codes.

Quite new to stackoverflow -> can one edit his/her questions ?, HOW if yes!

Comment: @OkechukwuEze I will suggest you to post new question. because existing question signature will change once you edit the question with new issue.

Comment: @OkechukwuEze  jily's answer is not complete. Please go through the link that I have suggest you in answer.

Comment: so how can u find the **NEW question ** when i post it ?

Comment: @OkechukwuEze past your code http://pastebin.com/ here and give me that link.  I will take a look.

Comment: @OkechukwuEze I can find your new question from your profile page.

Comment: i just posted my new code here
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525787/search-functionality-to-listview-using-baseadapter-not-populating-list-on-search

Comment: :: i have update the question on this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525787/search-functionality-to-listview-using-baseadapter-not-populating-list-on-search

Kindly look into it please.

Comment: @OkechukwuEze I was busy last few hours. looks like you got solution. :-)

Comment: Yes i got solution about that but follow up another issue i notice on this link i posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529720/can-not-reload-listview-content-after-implementing-filterable-interface-on-my-cu

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
  {
    public Filter getFilter() {
     return  new Filter(){

        @Override
        protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
           //This function performs filtering in worker thread
           // And return Filter.FilterResults

         }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
        {
                // update list from filter Result
                // and call notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };

  }
}
```

Comment: i was able to add this block of code which stoped the **getFilter** error but when i search, the listView contents remains the same!

can u still tell me what i am missing. I know i am close this time.

Comment: i just posted my update codes here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525787/search-functionality-to-listview-using-baseadapter-not-populating-list-on-search

Answer (score 0):

In on text changed call below method and place this method on adapter,always check "searchText" in your movies arraylist

```
// Filter Class
        private void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            searchText = charText;
            Log.i("installed apps==", searchText);
            appsList.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                appsList.addAll(arraylist);
            } else {
                for (AppPojo wp : arraylist) {
                    if (wp.getappName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                        appsList.add(wp);
                    }
                }

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```