# Search Functionality to ListView using BaseAdapter not populating List on search

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview

I have been trying to implement a simple search to a listView which I have been able to populate using Volley but all to no avail till date. Thanks to **@Dhaval Patel** who has been of greet help. But the issue I am having now is that when I search, the **ListView refuse to change content** thus making the whose search useless in the program

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ListView mList;
   private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
   EditText inputSearch;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


           adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
           mList.setAdapter(adapter);


        //SEARCH TEXTCHANGE
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                   // When user changed the Text
                  MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
                //FLAGS Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()' here
                }

             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             }
          });




    }



}
```

Also this is the code in my CustomListAdapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private Activity activity;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private List<Movie> movieItems;
     private String[] bgColors;
     private List<String>originalData = null;
     private List<String>filteredData = null;
     private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();


         public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
             this.activity = activity;
             this.movieItems = movieItems;
             bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
         }
         @Override
         public int getCount() {
                return movieItems.size();
         }

         @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
             return movieItems.get(location);
         }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
               return position;
            }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
              inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image, null);

             if (imageLoader == null)
              imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

             TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

            // getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

            // thumbnail image
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

            // title
            title.setText(m.getTitle());

            // rating
             rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

            // genre
            String genreStr = "";
            for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
              genreStr += str + ", ";
              }
            genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                 genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
             genre.setText(genreStr);

            // release year
             year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

             String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
            serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));




            return convertView;
     }



     public Filter getFilter() {
         return mFilter;
     }

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}



}
```

So can someone please tell me what I am not doing right.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you werent using Filter class im sure i could have easily resolve your issue, please wait for when i can find it easier to use Filter than doing it by myself.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue but noticed another issue which i have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529720/can-not-reload-listview-content-after-implementing-filterable-interface-on-my-cu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter { 
   @Override 
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    final List<Movie> list = movieItems;

    int count = list.size();
    final ArrayList<Movie> nlist = new ArrayList<Movie>(count);

    String filterableString ;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        filterableString = list.get(i).getName();
        if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
            nlist.add(list.get(i));
        } 
    } 

    results.values = nlist;
    results.count = nlist.size();

    return results;
} 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
@Override 
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    movieItems= (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
} 

}
```

Comment: Hi @jily  -   I replaced  **filterableString = list.get(i).getName();** with 
** filterableString = list.get(i).getTitle();**  

But the program flags on **nlist.add(filterableString);**

ERROR:: 'add(com.npi.blureffect.model.Movie)' in 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Comment: hi @OkechukwuEze ... add movie object to nlist ... i have edited the code.. check it out.

Comment: i can't believe i solve this search puzzle at last. Thanks to you and @sonic

But i realized that after searching which populates the list with the right list content **when i clear the EditView search data the list does not repopulate itself with the previous content** but rather retains only the searched result..


You know how i can revert the ListView with its previose content after i clear the EditView data ?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue but noticed another issue which i have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529720/can-not-reload-listview-content-after-implementing-filterable-interface-on-my-cu

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't use your `filteredData` in the adapter.
So when you call `notifiyDataSetChanged` there is no change in the data use to fill the `ListView`.

The `publishResults` method should change the data used to populate the views, ie for you the `movieItems` list.

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<Movie> list = originalMovieItems;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<Movie> nlist = new ArrayList<Movie>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i).getName();//or whatever you want to filter on
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        movieList = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

So to keep the movie list unchanged (not the one you display but the one you filter on), you should add a originalMovieList field to your adapter class and modify the constructor as following.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
     this.activity = activity;
     this.movieItems = movieItems;
     bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
      this.originalMovieList = movieItems;
         }
```

Comment: So he already has a method that does it well and doesnt know about it?

Comment: what exactly should i change on the **publishResults** method

Comment: protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

Comment: i repalced **filteredData** with **movieItems** in the method but it flags erros.

God know i am so so lost here. Dont know what exactly to do .
hhhmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: as @okechukwu-eze says you need to change the `filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;` line. It should be something like `movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;`. As it seems that `movieItems` are list of `Movie` bbject it will be a litte more than that. You can rebuild a list of movie object with the result list **or** (better) change your filter so it return a list of movie.

Comment: Thanks so fare @Sonic. Was able to replace the **movieItems** 
now the program flags on this line   **nlist.add(filterableString);**

Error:'add(com.npi.blureffect.model.Movie)' in 'java.util.ArrayList' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Comment: That's because you should change this line to `nList.add(filterableString)` to `nList.add(list.get(i))`. The goal of these edition, was to make your filter return a list of `Movie` instead of a list of `String`. So you should fill the result list with `Movie` object, not `String`.

Comment: if u choose to use **originalMovieList** does it imply that i would now change `final List<Movie> list = movieItems;` to `final List<Movie> list = originalMovieList;` and `movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;` to `originalMovieList = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;`  ???

Comment: i can't believe i solve this search puzzle at last. Thanks to @sonic 

But i realized that after searching which populates the list with the right list content **when i clear the EditView search data the list does not repopulate itself with the previous content** but rather retains only the searched result..


You know how i can revert the ListView with its previose content after i clear the EditView data ?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue but noticed another issue which i have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529720/can-not-reload-listview-content-after-implementing-filterable-interface-on-my-cu

Answer (score 1):

This is how i was able to solve the misery of my searching code.

on my **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private List<Movie> currentMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
 private List<Movie> originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
 private CustomListAdapter adapter;
 private ListView mList;
 // Search EditText
 EditText inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, currentMovieList);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);


    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            String filterString = cs.toString().toLowerCase();
            Log.e("TAG", "filterString:" + filterString);
            currentMovieList.clear();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filterString)) {
                currentMovieList.addAll(originalMovieList);
            }

            String filterableString;
            for (Movie movie : originalMovieList) {

            //search from the title field
                if (movie.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
            //search from the year field
                else if (String.valueOf(movie.getYear()).toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
            //search from the rating field
                else if (String.valueOf(movie.getRating()).toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
            //search from the genre field
                else if (movie.getGenre().toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //FLAGS Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()' here
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

}
}

And ADD this to your **CustomListAdapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Activity activity;
 private LayoutInflater inflater;

 private List<String>originalData = null;
 // private List<String>filteredData = null;

 private List<Movie> movieItems;
 private List<Movie> originalMovieList;
 private String[] bgColors;
 ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


 public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
       this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
      // this.originalMovieList = movieItems;
      this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
      bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
        }

    //Add Below Method
    public void reloadData(){
       this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return movieItems.size();
        }

 @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
        }

 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

     // genre
     String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
          genreStr += str + ", ";
     }
     genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
     year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

     String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
        serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));




      return convertView;
 }


            public Filter getFilter() {
                return mFilter;
            }

            private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


                    //results.values = nlist;
                    //results.count = nlist.size();
                    results.values = originalMovieList;
                    results.count = originalMovieList.size();

                    return results;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    //filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                    //movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
                    movieItems.clear();
                    movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }



}
```

Now thats a WRAP. Thanks to  **@DhavalPatel** That Guy is an Android Guru.
`He made all this happen`. 
-Happy Coding

Comment: @DhavalPatel Thanks once more.
You can vote for this answer if i answered it right. #wink