# Can not reload ListView Content after implementing Filterable interface on my CustomListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter, android-search

I have two questions here.

- **The First Question goes ::** After i implementing  `Filterable` interface in my CustomListAdapter to enable search on list data, i realized that each time i try to reload the listview, it refused to populate the listview even thought i was able to fetch the data from my server. (My ListView always reloads on device orientation change and i also added a reload button to reload the listView onclick too)
- **The Second Question goes ::** My search EditView populates my listView very well onchange but i realized that when i empty the EditView, the previous data in the ListView does not revert/come-back to its previous content

Below is my Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private ListView mList;
   private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
   EditText inputSearch;
       private CustomListAdapter adapter;
   private ImageView  reload_img;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
       inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
           reload_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reload_list);


           adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
           mList.setAdapter(adapter);

        //FETCH Movie-Data FROM SERVER TO LIST
         fetchMovie();

        //Reload image click
             reload_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    reload_list();
                    }
            });

        //SEARCH TEXTCHANGE
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                   // When user changed the Text
                  MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
                //FLAGS Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()' here
                }

             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             }
          });




    }


    //RELOAD LISTVIEW METHOD
            private void reload_list()
            {

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Showing progress dialog before making http request
                pDialog.setMessage("Synchronising....");
                pDialog.show();
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


                flag_loading = true;
                offSet = 0;
                inputSearch.setText("");
                movieList.clear();

                fetchMovie();
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }


    //LOAD DATA FROM SERVER TO LISTVIEW USING VOLLEY
    private void fetchMovie()
            {

                // showing refresh animation before making http call
                //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                // appending offset to url
               String url = Config.URL_TOP_250_URL + offSet;
                //String url = Config.MOVIE_JSON_URL;
               //String url = Config.MOVIE_JSON_URL_SHORT;

               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                 //       "::Json loaded:: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                // Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                hidePDialog();

                                if (response.length() > 0) {

                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                      //     "Json String : \n"+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    // Parsing json
                                   /**/ for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                        try {

                                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                            int rank = obj.getInt("rank");

                                            Movie movie = new Movie();

                                            // movie.setRank(obj.getInt("rank"));

                                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                                    .doubleValue());

                                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                            // Genre is json array
                                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                            }
                                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                                            // adding movie to movies array
                                            movieList.add(movie);

                                            // updating offset value to highest value
                                            if (rank >= offSet)
                                                offSet = rank;
                                            flag_loading = false;
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();

                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                    "Network connection error \n "+  e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                    /**/

                                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            "End of movie-list" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }


                            }




                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();


                    }

                });

                // Adding request to request queue
                MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
            }


}
```

And here is the code in my CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

         private Activity activity;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private List<Movie> movieItems;
      private List<Movie> originalMovieList;
         private String[] bgColors;
     private List<String>originalData = null;
     private List<String>filteredData = null;
     private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
         ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();


         public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
             this.activity = activity;
             this.movieItems = movieItems;
        this.originalMovieList = movieItems;
             bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
         }
         @Override
         public int getCount() {
                return movieItems.size();
         }

         @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
             return movieItems.get(location);
         }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
               return position;
            }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
              inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image, null);

             if (imageLoader == null)
              imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

             TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

            // getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

            // thumbnail image
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

            // title
            title.setText(m.getTitle());

            // rating
             rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

            // genre
            String genreStr = "";
            for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
              genreStr += str + ", ";
              }
            genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                 genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
             genre.setText(genreStr);

            // release year
             year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

             String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
            serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));




            return convertView;
     }




            public Filter getFilter() {
                return mFilter;
            }

            private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                    //final List<String> list = originalData;
                    final List<Movie> list = movieItems;

                    int count = list.size();
                   // final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);
                    final ArrayList<Movie> nlist = new ArrayList<Movie>(count);

                    String filterableString ;

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        filterableString = list.get(i).getTitle();
                        if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                           // nlist.add(filterableString);
                            nlist.add(list.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = nlist;
                    results.count = nlist.size();

                    return results;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    //filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                    movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }


}
```

As you see i really took my time to put this whole code together but at this junction, my head spins as i cant figure out why

- **On orientation change**, the listView data which use to rePopulate before suddenly stops populating after i introduced the **Filterable** to my **CustomListAdapter** class and also
- **When i clear the search EditView**, the content in the ListView does not return to
- **When i click on the reload button**, the content in the list does not reload, just like it does when the device orientation changes.

I would really appreciate a hint to help me out as i am so so stuck right now.
`Thanks in Advance`

-**Edited CustomListAdapter** the changes i made are

```
               @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    //filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                    //movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
                    movieItems.clear();
                    movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
```

also edited this too. Added `this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);`

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
   // this.originalMovieList = movieItems;
    this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
    bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
}
```

Added this method to CustomListAdapter

```
//Add Below Method
public void reloadData(){
    this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also replaced notifyDataSetChanged() in MainActivity Class with this

```
                     `// notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                     //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      adapter.reloadData();`
```

-Reload Button now works fine, Orientation change reloads the page well but the Search does not populate the ListView. **Thus, Search not working yet**

Comment: Try changing **this.originalMovieList = movieItems;** to **this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);** in adapter constructor.

Comment: @Dhaval-patel  ::i changed the  `this.originalMovieList = movieItems;` to this `this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);` and also i amended the following lines too `final List<Movie> list = movieItems` was now changed to `final List<Movie> list = originalMovieList;` and changed the method **publicResults** code too on `movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;` was changed to `originalMovieList = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;`

Comment: Which made the reload to work but the search search stopped working automatically

Comment: **final List<Movie> list = originalMovieList;** change is correct. but Instead of **movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values** try **movieItems clear(); movieItems .addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);** in publishResults method.

Comment: on orientation change the lisView repopulates but  when i click the button it refuse to populate the list after loading. **the search does not work also**

Comment: Added this lines to publicResults method `movieItems.clear(); movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);`

Comment: Still search not working?

Comment: @DhavalPatel  `movieItems.clear();
                        movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);` is already in `publishResults` but search is still not working..

Comment: Please try [this](http://pastebin.com/xiVsZSDw) code.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Thanks for the link. Using ur guild make the reload button work well and Listview reload when page orientation change but the search still not working at all. entring text in the EditView does nothing as the listView data remains the same.

Comment: wish i know how to figure out this issue myself. You have been very helpful. I really appreciate. Something tells me we are close to the solution.

Comment: i have update my question codes with ur suggestion here.

Comment: Looks like problem in for loop of performFiltering method. Try [this](http://pastebin.com/R6gCqVXq) code.

Comment: i have update the code on this Link http://pastebin.com/RXGjrg4u
I added your code but no basic difference was noticed as search dont work and most times, the reload does not return well but rather returns empty sometimes and sometimez does not even clear the list.

Comment: Not sure why this happening to you. as a last option try http://pastebin.com/YGcyS6ML code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are answers to your questions:

1. The `ListView` is not reloaded? After looking at your code at function:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
         //filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
         movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The aboved function make your adapter cant reload of course. Why? Because this line: `movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;`. You reference your `movieItems` in adapter to another `List` so `movieList.add(movie);` d in your `MainActivity` doesnot chang anything in your `adapter` any more. How to overcome it? Change as below:

```
movieItems.clear();
movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However, Your `Search` function still doesnt work. Why? Because in `performFiltering` you tried to search in `movieItems` not your backup data. --> you should search in your back up data: `originalMovieList`, then publish by adding in `movieItems`.

```
//change final List<Movie> list = movieItems;
//to belowed line in peformFiltering
final List<String> list = originalData;
```

2. Why your adapter not reverted? Because you control it, but you dont revert it. You should revert it in your `peformFiltering` function:

   ```
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
         if(TextUtils.isEmpty(filterString)){
               // do restore backup data here
         }else{
              // do filter here.
         }
   }
   ```

Comment: very happy for ur assistance and time. will apply to my code and update you. Though i have already adjusted my publicResult method to have `movieItems.clear();
                    movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();` already before now. Have also updated in in this question.

Comment: I dont know what exactly u mean by `// do restore backup data here` and also what u mean by `// do filter here.` in ur `if statement` as all i tried were kinda flagging on the program.

-Maybe u should maybe populate the **do restore backup data here** aspect of the `if condition` so that i can have an idea of what you are implying

Comment: i want to belive u did a mistake here when u said i should use `final List<String> list = originalData;` cos originalData has not been declared/instantiated any were in the program.

- did u mean `final List<Movie> list = originalMovieList;` ?

Comment: on this link is my updated code.. http://pastebin.com/RXGjrg4u

It will help u see how my codes are now with all the changes i have made

Comment: @OkechukwuEze yes, it's my typo mistake. In `do restore backup`, you should restore your original data such as: ` results.values = originalMovieList; results.count = originalMovieList.size();`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to solve the misery of my searching code.

on my **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private List<Movie> currentMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
 private List<Movie> originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
 private CustomListAdapter adapter;
 private ListView mList;
 // Search EditText
 EditText inputSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, currentMovieList);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);


    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            String filterString = cs.toString().toLowerCase();
            Log.e("TAG", "filterString:" + filterString);
            currentMovieList.clear();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filterString)) {
                currentMovieList.addAll(originalMovieList);
            }

            String filterableString;
            for (Movie movie : originalMovieList) {
                if (movie.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
                else if (String.valueOf(movie.getYear()).toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
                else if (String.valueOf(movie.getRating()).toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
                else if (movie.getGenre().toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterString))
                {
                    currentMovieList.add(movie);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //FLAGS Cannot resolve method 'getFilter()' here
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });


}
}
```

And ADD this to your **CustomListAdapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Activity activity;
 private LayoutInflater inflater;

 private List<String>originalData = null;
 // private List<String>filteredData = null;

 private List<Movie> movieItems;
 private List<Movie> originalMovieList;
 private String[] bgColors;
 ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


 public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
       this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
      // this.originalMovieList = movieItems;
      this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
      bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
        }

    //Add Below Method
    public void reloadData(){
       this.originalMovieList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movieItems);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return movieItems.size();
        }

 @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
        }

 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_image, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

     // genre
     String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
          genreStr += str + ", ";
     }
     genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
     year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

     String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
        serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));




      return convertView;
 }


            public Filter getFilter() {
                return mFilter;
            }

            private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


                    //results.values = nlist;
                    //results.count = nlist.size();
                    results.values = originalMovieList;
                    results.count = originalMovieList.size();

                    return results;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    //filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                    //movieItems = (ArrayList<Movie>) results.values;
                    movieItems.clear();
                    movieItems.addAll((ArrayList<Movie>) results.values);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }



}
```

Now thats a WRAP. **Thanks to @DhavalPatel** That Guy is an Android Guru. `He made all this happen. -Happy Coding`