# Filtering custom list adapter Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am trying to have a search filter in my Custom list Adapter. I am still facing small problems after I tried something looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android).
I am having problem in the line where I have commented in my code.

**My adapter class**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<ContactLists> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private List<String>filteredData = null;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactLists> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ....
    ....
    return convertView;
}
    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;

}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); 
        final List<String> list = listData; // I am having a problem here. 
        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: Dude they have used 2 arraylist. check their constructor.

Comment: i cannot set `final List<String> list = listData;` 
Require <java.lang.String>

Comment: _"I am having a problem here."_ What it is?

Answer (score 0):

Because your List is a string type and you are assigning it to arrayList of model

Answer (score 0):

list is of `String` type and `listData` if of `ContactLists`. Make sure you that both array lists are of the same type.