# Android SearchView with custom listview

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

[image]
Can someone help me to do this please? i want to search item from `listview` using `SearchView`. Here's my code

This is the ListObat.java

```
package co.id.zsoft.apotikstore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListObat extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_obat);

        ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails) o;
                Toast.makeText(ListObat.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

        ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Pizza");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Spicy Chiken Pizza");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 310.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Beef Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 350.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Pizza");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Chiken Pizza");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 250.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Chicken Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 350.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Fish Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 310.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(5);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Mango");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Mango Juice");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 250.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(6);
        results.add(item_details);


        return results;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_obat, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the ItemDetails.java

```
package co.id.zsoft.apotikstore;

/**
 * Created by rsr_unitedstate on 12/18/2015.
 */
public class ItemDetails {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getItemDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }
    public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getImageNumber() {
        return imageNumber;
    }
    public void setImageNumber(int imageNumber) {
        this.imageNumber = imageNumber;
    }

    private String name ;
    private String itemDescription;
    private String price;
    private int imageNumber;
}
```

This is the ItemListBaseAdapter.java

```
package co.id.zsoft.apotikstore;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by rsr_unitedstate on 12/18/2015.
 */
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

    private Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.testimage,
            R.drawable.testimage,
            R.drawable.testimage,
            R.drawable.testimage,
            R.drawable.testimage,
            R.drawable.testimage
    };

    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            holder.txt_qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Qty);
            holder.btnkurang = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnkurang);
            holder.btntambah = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btntambah);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
        holder.txt_itemPrice.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
//      imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://192.168.1.28:8082/ANDROID/images/BEVE.jpeg", holder.itemImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        TextView txt_itemPrice;
        TextView txt_qty;
        ImageView itemImage;
        ImageButton btntambah;
        ImageButton btnkurang;
    }
}
```

This is the activity_list_obat.xml as listview layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="co.id.zsoft.apotikstore.ListObat">


    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the item_details_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nama Obat"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/photo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Harga Obat"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/photo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nama Apotik"
        android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/photo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/Qty"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/photo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnkurang"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Qty"
        android:src="@drawable/minus"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btntambah"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnkurang"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search view comes in the action bar. Therefore menu items need to be set up.

```
/*******************
     * Menu Items
     ******************/

   /*
    Menu added to perform search on the action bar. Two menu items:
    2. Open the search area on the action bar so that the user can search.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        final SearchView sv = new SearchView(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        sv.setFocusable(true);
        sv.setIconified(false);
        sv.clearFocus();
        sv.requestFocusFromTouch();

        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);


        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                sv.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
                sv.setFocusable(true);
                sv.setIconified(false);
                sv.requestFocusFromTouch();
                return false;
            }
        });

        sv.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                item.collapseActionView();
                hideKeyboard();
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search), new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

                //DO SOMETHING WHEN THE SEARCHVIEW IS CLOSING
                simpleSearch = null;
                sv.setQuery(null, false);
                hideKeyboard();
                return true;
            }
        });

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                System.out.println("search query submit");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchString) {
                System.out.println(searchString);
                classSearchArray.clear();
                if (searchString.length() > 0) {
                    simpleSearch = searchString.toLowerCase();
                    for (ClassModel classObj : classArray) {
                        if (classObj.getName().toLowerCase().contains(simpleSearch) ||
                                classObj.getCity().toLowerCase().contains(simpleSearch) ||
                                classObj.getStaffName().toLowerCase().contains(simpleSearch) ||
                                classObj.getLocationName().toLowerCase().contains(simpleSearch)) {

                            classSearchArray.add(classObj);
                        }
                    }
                    ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(classSearchArray, getActivity(), FindAClassFragment.this);
                    listViewSearch.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //original list view
                    listViewSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //search list view

                } else {
                    simpleSearch = null;
                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    listViewSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search Items"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: thanks for your explaination. now i can use searchview

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search products.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <!-- List View -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Single ListItem -->

    <!-- Product Name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }    
}
```