# Filter ListView in Navigation Drawer with EditText

Tags: android, listview, filter, navigation-drawer

The image shows the `ListView` in navigation drawer, I added `EditText` to filter the list But I am not able to achieve this. please help me how to this!!! My code is given below!! Thanks!!!
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ImageView home;
Fragment fragment = null;
TextView appname;
ListView listView;
// CustomAdapter customAdapter;
MyArrayAdapter myAdapter;
List<String> listData;
EditText inputSearch;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);

    home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
    appname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
    fragment = new MapFragment();
    setUpDrawer();

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

/**
 * 
 * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
 */
private void setUpDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vechileCheck);
    prepareListData();
    myAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, listData);
    // setting list adapter
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    // fragment = new MapFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);

}

View.OnClickListener homeOnclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(linearLayout)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    }
};

private OnItemClickListener mDrawerItemClickedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
    }
};

// Catch the events related to the drawer to arrange views according to this
// action if necessary...
private DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    }
};

private void prepareListData() {
    listData = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding child data
    listData.add("Vechile-1");
    listData.add("Vechile-2");
    listData.add("Vechile-3");
    listData.add("Vechile-4");
    listData.add("Vechile-5");
    listData.add("Vechile-6");
    listData.add("Vechile-7");
    listData.add("Vechile-8");
    listData.add("Vechile-9");
    listData.add("wakie");

}
```

}

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listData;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> listData) {
    super(context, -1, listData);

    this._context = context;
    this._listData = listData;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._listData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return this._listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getItem(position);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return view;
}
```

}
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVBP0.png)

Comment: Here is answer for you [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/5085440)

Comment: @hungdh0x5e Yaa its working!!! The filtered data is showing only when i press the next button on the keyboard. What I want is display the filtered data as soon as i change the data inthe EditText.