# ListView setOnItemClickListener not working after implementing search

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a simple listview inside a dialog which has a search function. The search function is working fine, but the list's setOnItemClickListener stops working after a search is performed.

**Function to create the listview:**

```
private void showCollegePopUp(){
        QustomDialogBuilder builder = new QustomDialogBuilder(EditYourProfile.this);
        builder.setDividerColor(ColorController.bright_green);

        View v = builder.setCustomView(R.layout.dialog_friend_layout, this);

        final ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_friends);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)EditYourProfile.this.getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_college_list_footer, list, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);


        inputSearch = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.add_college);

        textView.setTypeface(TypeFaceController.generalTextFace(EditYourProfile.this));

        LinearLayout footer_linear_layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.footer_linear_layout);
        footer_linear_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(EditYourProfile.this, CreateCollegeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (listOfCollegeCourseNames.size() == 0) {
            listOfCollegeCourseNames.add("Grabbing colleges...");
        }

        adapter = new CustomDialogAdapterBasic(EditYourProfile.this, android.R.id.text1, listOfCollegeCourseNames);
        list.setPadding(16, 0, 0, 0);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            //Event when changed word on EditTex
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.e("Text", "Text [" + s + "]");

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });
        builder.setTitle("Select your college");
        builder.setMessage("Choose College from the list:");
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){

            }
        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                // Do as you please

                if (adapter.getItem(position).toString().equals(collegeData.get(position).getNameForCollege())
                        || adapter.getItem(position).toString().equals(collegeData.get(position).getStudentsNameForCollege())) {

                    newCollegeName = adapter.getItem(position).toString();

                    collegeEditPage.setText(Html.fromHtml((newCollegeName)));// +
                                                                                // edit));
                    //courseEditPage.setText(Html.fromHtml(("Must choose new course")));// +
                                                                                        // edit));
                    // course doesn't exist anymore.
                    studentObject.setCourseName(null);
                    studentObject.setCollegeName(newCollegeName);

                    if (EditYourProfile.this.alertDialog != null) {
                        EditYourProfile.this.alertDialog.dismiss();
                        // Refresh the list used.
                        listOfCollegeCourseNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                        newCollegeId = collegeData.get(position).getCollegeUnqId();
                        studentObject.setCollegeId(newCollegeId);
                    }

                }

            }
        });

        this.alertDialog = builder.create();
        this.alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                Button button = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                button.setTextSize(17);
                button.setTypeface(TypeFaceController.titleFace(getApplicationContext()));
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

**Listview's adapter that supports search functionality:**

```
public class CustomDialogAdapterBasic extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    List<String> valuesComingIn = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valuesFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


    public CustomDialogAdapterBasic(Context context, int resource, List<String> listComingIn) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.valuesComingIn = listComingIn;
        this.valuesFiltered = listComingIn;
    }


    public void updateBrowser() {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return valuesFiltered.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        return valuesFiltered.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qustom_layout_list, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.basic_text_view);

        textView.setTypeface(TypeFaceController.generalTextFace(context));
        textView.setText(getItem(position));

        return rowView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            Log.e("filterString", filterString);

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = valuesComingIn;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            valuesFiltered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

**Listview row layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basic_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The layout of the dialog containing listview:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search colleges.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_list_view_friends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is the `setOnItemClickListener` not working after search?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way to implement clickListener
public class CustomDialogAdapterBasic extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    List<String> valuesComingIn = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valuesFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


    public CustomDialogAdapterBasic(Context context, int resource, List<String> listComingIn) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.valuesComingIn = listComingIn;
        this.valuesFiltered = listComingIn;
    }


    public void updateBrowser() {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return valuesFiltered.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        return valuesFiltered.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qustom_layout_list, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.basic_text_view);

        textView.setTypeface(TypeFaceController.generalTextFace(context));
        textView.setText(getItem(position));
textView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(getItem(position)));
        return rowView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    class Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    String textData;
    Listener(String textData)
    {
    this.textData = textData;
    }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // Implement your click functionality here and call any method of activity like this
          // ((ActivityName)context).methodName();
        }
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            Log.e("filterString", filterString);

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = valuesComingIn;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            valuesFiltered = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How will I be able to access these parameters: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Comment: Also it is a click listener for the TextView, not the list item

Comment: yes you can also implement the click view on a inflated view but in case of list item or list view you need to implemnt the listener in such maner

Comment: you can get the item individually and also pass the item the like position in the Listener constructor

Comment: In your adapter i write a listener Class and i write the way how to call a method in activity and you can also pass parameters in that fuunction. In the same way as i can pass the String in Listner constructor you can pass the postion as well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the parent layout of XML.

Comment: please check layouts in the question