# How to filter arrayadapter in android

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter

In my application I have created a adapter list  and I want to use a filter so that the list can be filtered according to the text entered in the EditText. I am using a ArrayAdapter . I have also implemented the addTextChangedListener() in my main activity. now it doing the filter after it append,
But it does not work as I expect it to work.

for example:

I have 3 strings in my array string called :treesNumbers[]

*2080

0506582039

0506582038

and my ArrayAdapter  gets the treesNumbers array:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>   (getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_search,R.id.tree_name, treesNumbers);
```

if I will enter the character * it will do the filter but return after filter

*2080

0506582039

0506582038

and I expected it to return:
*2080

and only after I enter the character 2 it will return after filter 
*2080

if I will  enter the character 6 it will return after filter 
*2080
and only if I will enter any character I will get:
" "

What can I do to solve this problem?

The code of Activity class:

```
    number.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            if( treesNumbers != null) {

                    if (adapter == null) {
                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_search, R.id.tree_name, treesNumbers);
                    }
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                filteredData = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
                        filteredData.add(adapter.getItem(i));

                countSearch.setText(String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()));
                if (adapter.getCount() > 0){
                       inputSearch.setText(adapter.getItem(0));
                       linearLayoutSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                else {
                       inputSearch.setText("");
                       linearLayoutSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I tried to do that with custom Listview Adapter with filter Android
It does not work and it still exactly what I have described. Again- I can do filter but the results still as I did above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Comment: It does not work and it still exactly what I have described.
Again- I can do filter  but the results still as I did above