# notify Adapter's dataSource when object didnt exists anymore

Tags: java, android, searchview

i have  `SearchView` in my `RecyclerView`,  user can delete the objects of this  `RecyclerView` but when user searches for anything and deletes a object from the results this is where   am having problem ,   when the search is not active am using a `DefaultArrayList` of Objects but when the searchBar is Active my  result Objects are shown in another ArrayList  named as `FilteredArrayList` and when i delete an item from array list the object is got deleted from the `FilteredArrayList` and from `DataBase` but not from the `DefaultArrayList` so when the search ends the same deleted file still remains at the `DefaultArrayList`

so any idea how can i notify the `DefaultArrayList` that the Object is not exists anymore (which is still cached the `DefaultArrayList` ) ???

well i tried this :

```
myAdapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but it's not doing the job

Comment: You need to delete it from `DefaultArrayList` by calling `DefaultArrayList.remove(index)` and then if you notify the adapter with `myAdapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged()` it should work.

Comment: @TychoTheTaco but bro the point is this i can't , because right now DeafultArray is not the incharge right now View is using FilteredArray and the index of filterArray will be different then Deafultarray's Index

Comment: Then just get a reference to `DefaultArrayList` and then get the object from `FilterredArrayList` and call `DefaultArrayList.remove(object)`

Answer (score 1):

`myAdapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();` is not the problem here.
You need to delete the item from both `FilteredArrayList` and `DefaultArrayList`.

Another solution for your problem is to use only one `ArrayList`. and inside your `Adapter` implement the [`Filterable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface. Refer to this [Filterable example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/2185634) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing that `DefaultArrayList` as data source to `FilteredArrayList` instead of copying+filtering? In pseudocode:

```
View {

   defaultList: DefaultArrayList;

   showSearchBar() {
      filteredList = new FilteredArrayList(this.defaultList);
      ...
      this.searchBar.show(filteredList);
   }

}


FilteredArrayList {

   FilteredArrayList(dataSource) {
     this.dataSource = dataSource;
   }

   enumerator() {
      ...
      // filtered items enumeration from dataSource
      ...
   }

   delete(item) {
      this.dataSource.delete(item);
      // also delete from filtered cache if needed
   }

}
```

Also it can be implemented with `delegates` or `observers`:

```
ListActionsDelegate {

   onDelete(Item item);

}

View ... implements ListActionsDelegate {

   defaultList: DefaultArrayList;

   onDelete(Item item) {
      this.defaultList.delete(item);
   }

   showSearchBar() {
      filteredList = new FilteredArrayList(this.defaultList);
      filteredList.delegate = this;
      ...
      this.searchBar.show(filteredList);
   }
}

FilteredArrayList {

   delegate: ListActionsDelegate;

   FilteredArrayList(items) {
     this.raw = items;
   }

   delete(item) {
      super.delete(item);

      if (this.delegate)
         this.delegate.onDelete(item); // notify list actions delegate
   }

}
```