# Implement Filter on Listview multiple times android

Tags: android, listview, android-filter, android-filterable

I am able to implement filter on listview successfully wherein the filtered item in listview can be displayed in edittext when I click on that item. Now, the problem is once the text is filtered and the selected item is displayed in edittext, the filter does not work for the second word I type in edittext. How to do it?

Example: If I write **mercury in edittext**, **listview will contain mercury** as option. Now **Edittext has mercury venus** as text, I want list to **filter on venus as well while mercury is already there** in edittext.

Here is the code I am using.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // The data to show
    List<Planet> planetsList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    PlanetAdapter aAdpt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initList();

        // We get the ListView component from the layout
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);

        aAdpt = new PlanetAdapter(planetsList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

        // React to user clicks on item
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {


                editTxt.setText(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString());
            }
        });

        // we register for the contextmneu
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        // TextFilter
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (count < before) {
                    // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                    aAdpt.resetData();
                }

                aAdpt.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void initList() {
        // We populate the planets

        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mercury", 10));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Venus", 20));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mars", 30));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 40));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Saturn", 50));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Uranus", 60));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Neptune", 70));


    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements Filterable {

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    private Filter planetFilter;
    private List<Planet> origPlanetList;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.img_row_layout, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.origPlanetList = planetList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_row_layout, null);
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);


            holder.planetNameView = tv;
            holder.distView = distView;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();

        Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());


        return v;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        planetList = origPlanetList;
    }


    private static class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetNameView;
        public TextView distView;
    }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (planetFilter == null)
            planetFilter = new PlanetFilter();

        return planetFilter;
    }



    private class PlanetFilter extends Filter {



        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = origPlanetList;
                results.count = origPlanetList.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Planet> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

                for (Planet p : planetList) {
                    if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nPlanetList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nPlanetList;
                results.count = nPlanetList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                planetList = (List<Planet>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Comment: Probably the problem is here-
`for (Planet p : planetList) {
                if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    nPlanetList.add(p);
            }`
in the above code change **planetList** to **origPlanetList**

Comment: The community [has discussed begging for urgency in questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly resolved it is unacceptable.

Comment: @halfer I will take a note of it. Since, I am new here, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is not specific to Stack Overflow. The (fairly obvious) point is that if you are addressing volunteers, don't try to place any duty, burden or social obligation upon them. Your urgencies are your own, everywhere on the internet.