# Working with TextWatcher and ListView

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I have a `String[]` called `lv_arr`, and my activity looks like this:

[image: which looks like this]

It contains a `EditText` and below that I am displaying a above `lv_arr[]` using this code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,lv_arr);  
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Currently `lv_arr[]` contains only one string (i.e `"Notes"`), and whenever the user adds a string it will be updated. I want to add `TextWatcher` on my `EditText`, so I tried the following:

```
   <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addLabelText"
        android:hint="Add Label">
        <requestFocus/>

    </EditText>
```

With:

```
addLabelText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addLabelText);
        addLabelText.addTextChangedListener(listWatcher);
}

private  final TextWatcher listWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };
```

I want a final output which, whenever user types anything in that `EditText`, the significant values from my list should be displayed below it. When that `EditText` is goes to a blank state, the below list should display all elements. Otherwise only matching values should be visible.

I tried using a for loop so that I can get matching values, but I am making a mistake somewhere...

Comment: use this http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example it is simple way of serching EditText.....

Comment: follow https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html .

Comment: use auto complete text view instead of edittext

Comment: hey i  have posted solution try it. and let me know .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to achieve my desired output i write code as follows:

1) i changed my EditText to SearchView

```
<SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addLabelText"
            />
```

2)added setOnQueryTextListener on SearchView

```
addLabelText =(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.addLabelText);
        addLabelText.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

3)implement QueryTextChangeListener
4)Then,

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
```

Here adapter is the adapter that i used for my List View,
i.e

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,lv_arr);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Reference Link:  http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/android-filters-for-simple-listview.html

Comment: @vasrshavalanju Please Help me i have a dynamic list view i want to add text watcher . when i am write name it is filter on list view and show select list item that can i provide in edit text

Answer (score 0):

Use [Filterable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html).

And here it is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android) for example.

Comment: thanx @akash, for directing me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using filterable.

Try like below:

```
private  final TextWatcher listWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

Implement Filterable to Adapter and code like below

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (itemFilter == null) {
        itemFilter = new ItemFilter();
    }
    return itemFilter;

}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        final String searchString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        Log.i("TAG", "Query=>" + constraint);
        final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString() != "") {
            doctorsList.clear();
            // search content in DoctorList list
            for (i=0;i<itemNameArray.length();i++) {
                if (itemNameArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                    arrayList.add(itemNameArray[i]);

                }
            }

            filterResults.count = arrayList.size();
            Log.i("TAG", "FilterResultCount=>" + filterResults.count);
            filterResults.values = arrayList;
            Log.i("TAG", "FilterResultValues=>" + filterResults.values);

        } else {

            filterResults.count = arrayList.size();
            filterResults.values = arrayList;

        }
        return filterResults;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("TAG", "SearchResult" + arrayList);


    }
}
```

Comment: thanx @vishal, but i got the easiest way to achieve my output as akash suggested to use filterable

Comment: @varshavalanju i am also told you use same i think you didn't read answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Search Filter

```
addLabelText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my answer here - might be useful for someone

I was trying to fix this - not able to get the position when list view -> edit text has a text watcher.

This is the solution that worked for me :

In get view -

when I am add text watcher listener to edit text, I also added the below line

edittext.setTag(R.id.position, position)

in your afterTextChanged - 
 int position = edittext.getTag(R.id.position)

Gives the correct position number and you can do modifications based on the position number.