# Listview filter not works properly

Tags: android, listview

I have tried to perform the listview filter. But that filtering sometimes doesn't work properly. Sometimes its works correctly. I don't know how this error occurs. I've tried this:

```
 public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<HomepageGS> filterList = new ArrayList<HomepageGS>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getsearchjob_title().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        HomepageGS contacts = new HomepageGS();


                        HomepageGS m = mStringFilterList.get(i);
                        filterList.add(m);
                    }


                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count =  filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            mainpagelist1 = (List<HomepageGS>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

[image: [This is image not filter properly]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4LB3.png)

[image: [This image filter properly]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14nVr.png)

Comment: Here this question answered already. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android) may help you.