# Android search filter listview

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Ok I've tried several answers found here and I still couldn't do it, I think mainly because I don't know how the all these filter actually work. So I was wondering if you guys can help me with my code. I'm currently following the answer from here:

[Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android/24771174#24771174)

and I don't understand where the "mSeachableAdapter" in his MainActivity came from. Can someone help me fix my code? Also, please confirm whether I'm using the right method to filter listview.

MainActivity:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           //this one
 mSearchableAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

CustomAdapter.java: (The filter adapter i follow from the link)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String>originalData = null;
private List<String>filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.filteredData = data ;
    this.originalData = data ;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_team_list, null);

        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
    holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

TeamList.java: (I'm just putting this here just in case it is needed)

```
public class TeamList extends ArrayAdapter<Team> {
private Activity context;
List<Team> teams;



public TeamList(Activity context, List<Team> teams) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_team_list, teams);
    this.context = context;
    this.teams = teams;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_team_list, null, true);

    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewSport = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewSport);
    TextView textViewDate = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    TextView textViewTime = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    final TextView textViewNumber = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.icon);


    final Team team = teams.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(team.getTeamName());
    textViewSport.setText(team.getTeamSport());
    textViewDate.setText(team.getDate());
    textViewTime.setText(team.getTime());

    databaseMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long childCount = dataSnapshot.child("members").child(team.getTeamName()).child("teamMember").getChildrenCount();
            textViewNumber.setText(childCount + "/" + String.valueOf(team.getTeamNumber()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    String mDrawableName = team.getTeamSport();
    try{
        int ImgID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(ImgID);
        icon.setBackground(drawable);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listViewItem;
}


}
```

Really hope someone can guide me through all these, if there's any insufficient information ,let me know. Really appreciate it.

Comment: What are you exactly getting after using this code?

Comment: copy performFiltering() in your adapter and perform filter

Comment: The mSearchableAdapter is the adapter, in your case CustomAdapter. You need to call .getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString()); on the instance of your adapter to perform filtering.

Comment: @TP89 If i put CustomAdapter, the getfilter() will be on red line saying "Non-static method 'getfilter()' cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: You need to call the method from the instance you have of your adapter.