# How to filter content in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

I googled other solutions but coudn't find any whic is similar to my condition and at first i tried to get the contents of the text view and filter but was not successful please help. so here I have Created a listview which is inflated by three textviews which form like a table each textview is a column and data is added dynamically from the server. How Can filter contents based on the user search.
Here is the code Below.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private void showJSON2(String response){
    String id="";
    String name="";
    String date_from="";
    String date_to="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY2);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(i);
            id = notice.getString(KEY_ID);
            name = notice.getString(KEY_NAME);
            date_from = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_FROM);
            date_to = notice.getString(KEY_DATE_TO);

            HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, id);
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, name);
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, date_from);
            temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, date_to);
            list.add(temp);

        }

        ListViewAdapters adapter = new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
            {
                int pos=position+1;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(pos)+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

ListViewAdapters.java -

```
public class ListViewAdapters extends BaseAdapter{
public ListViewAdapters(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.colmn_row, null);
        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    }
    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic `Filterable` adapter (instead of `BaseAdapter`) as a base class of your adapter and override just two methods `onBind()` and `matches()`

Comment: how would you filter? using what value?

Comment: @npk The value which user enters.

Comment: @pskink Could you please provide me with an example i am having a hard time working it out. Thank You.

Comment: something like this: `class YourCustomAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<YourPOJOClass> { ...` and override those 2 above methods + constructor that takes `ArrayList` in your case

Comment: @pskink Well not exactly i actually opted to database searching as i wanted to add filters also. But Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MainActivity.java,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ListViewAdapters adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_default);

        adapter = new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void showJSON2(String response) {
        ...
        list.clear();
        ...
        list.add(temp);
        ...

        // ListViewAdapters adapter = new ListViewAdapters(this, list);
        // listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ...
    }

}
```

In adapter class,

```
public class ListViewAdapters extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> origList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListViewAdapters(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
        this.origList=list;
    }

    ...

    void filter(String filterString) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (HashMap<String, String> item: origList) {
            // use your own logic to filter
            if (itemShouldBeAdded)
                list.add(item); // add if item is inside filter
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    void cancelFilter() {
        list = origList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Now, to filter, call the function filter.

```
adapter.filter("some_string");
```

To cancel filter,

```
adapter.cancelFilter();
```

Comment: Why not use `Filterable` interface? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android

Comment: I don't know about it :(

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way to filter my list according to user's input.

```
   private void setFilter(EditText et_search_bar, ArrayList<String> list, OnListUpdated onListUpdated) {

    if (et_search_bar != null) {
        TextWatcher textWatcher;
        textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // filter your list from your input
                if (!previousValue.equalsIgnoreCase(s.toString())) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString())) {
                        previousValue = s.toString();
                        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String bookmarkBean : list) {
                            //or use .contains(text)
                            if (bookmarkBean.toLowerCase().contains(s.toString())) {
                                temp.add(bookmarkBean);
                            }
                        }
                        //update recyclerview
                        if (onListUpdated != null) {


                            onListUpdated.onListFiltered(temp);
                        }
                    } else onListUpdated.onListFiltered(filterBean);
                }
            }
        };
        et_search_bar.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }
}
```

and

```
        public interface OnListUpdated {
        void onListFiltered(ArrayList<String> list);}



        setFilter(et_search_bar, filterBean, new OnListUpdated() {
        @Override
        public void onListFiltered(ArrayList<String> list) {
        //                notify your adapter
        }
        });
```