# A Search doesn't update my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, search, android-recyclerview

I'm currently developing an Android application which can either load information from my website or use the information stored in an SQLite database. I'm trying to implement a search feature into it but I ran into a problem.

The data in my recyclerview doesn't update when a search is made. I've looked it up on Google many times but I still haven't found a solution. Is there a bright person here willing to help me?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DienstAdapter.ListItemClickListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String DIENST_URL = "https://mywebsite.com/apps/test/dienstenapi.php";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DienstAdapter adapter;

    private List<Dienst> dienstList;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private Cursor cursor;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private View headerView;
    private TextView gebruikersnaam;
    private Resources res;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swiper;
    private static Toast mToast = null;

    private SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        gebruikersnaam = headerView.findViewById(R.id.gebruikersnaam);
        res = getResources();

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);

        setupPreferenceGebruikersnaam();

        swiper = findViewById(R.id.swiper);
        swiper.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                dienstList.clear();
                loadDiensten();
            }
        });

        dienstList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DienstDbHelper dbHelper = new DienstDbHelper(this);
        mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        loadDiensten();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if (key.equals("example_text")){
                setupPreferenceGebruikersnaam();
            }
        }
    };

    private void loadDienstenOnline() {
        String moetInfoOphalen = sharedPreferences.getString("example_list", "1");
        if (moetInfoOphalen.equals("1") || moetInfoOphalen.equals("0")) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, DIENST_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray diensten = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < diensten.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject dienstObject = diensten.getJSONObject(i);

                            int id = dienstObject.getInt("id");
                            String naam = dienstObject.getString("naam");
                            String beschrijving = dienstObject.getString("beschrijving");
                            String categorie = dienstObject.getString("categorie");
                            double prijs = dienstObject.getDouble("prijs");
                            String afbeelding = dienstObject.getString("afbeelding");

                            dienstList.add(new Dienst(id, naam, beschrijving, categorie, prijs, afbeelding));
                        }

                        voegDienstenToeAanDb(mDb, dienstList);

                        adapter = new DienstAdapter(MainActivity.this, dienstList, MainActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        } else {
            loadDienstenOffline();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.instelling_blokkeert_ophalen_diensten, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadDienstenOffline() {
        cursor = getAlleDiensten();
        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            omzettenCursorNaarDiensten(cursor);
            adapter = new DienstAdapter(MainActivity.this, dienstList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            dienstList.add(new Dienst(0, "", "", "", 0, ""));
            adapter = new DienstAdapter(MainActivity.this, dienstList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (mToast != null)
                mToast.cancel();
            mToast.makeText(this, R.string.internet_werkt_niet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean internetIsBeschikbaar() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        assert cm != null;
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    private void loadDiensten() {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (internetIsBeschikbaar()) {
            loadDienstenOnline();
        } else {
            loadDienstenOffline();
        }
        swiper.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(String url, String naam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DienstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
        intent.putExtra("DienstNaam", naam);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager != null ? searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()) : null);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            return true;
        } else  if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return;
        }

        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                return;
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private static void voegDienstenToeAanDb(SQLiteDatabase db, List<Dienst> diensten){
        if(db == null){
            return;
        }

        List<ContentValues> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentValues cv;

        for (Dienst d : diensten) {
            cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_NAAM, d.getNaam());
            cv.put(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_BESCHRIJVING, d.getBeschrijving());
            cv.put(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIE, d.getCategorie());
            cv.put(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_PRIJS, d.getPrice());
            cv.put(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_AFBEELDING, d.getAfbeelding());
            list.add(cv);
        }

        try
        {
            db.beginTransaction();
            //clear the table first
            db.delete (DienstContract.DienstEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,null);
            //go through the list and add one by one
            for(ContentValues c : list){
                db.insert(DienstContract.DienstEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, c);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            //too bad :(
        }
        finally
        {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    private Cursor getAlleDiensten() {
        return mDb.query(
                DienstContract.DienstEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                DienstContract.DienstEntry._ID
        );
    }

    private void omzettenCursorNaarDiensten(Cursor c) {
        int teller = 0, id;
        String naam, beschrijving, categorie, afbeelding;
        double prijs;
        while (c.moveToPosition(teller)) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry._ID)));
            naam = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_NAAM));
            beschrijving = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_BESCHRIJVING));
            categorie = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIE));
            prijs = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_PRIJS));
            afbeelding = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DienstContract.DienstEntry.COLUMN_AFBEELDING));
            dienstList.add(new Dienst(id, naam, beschrijving, categorie, prijs, afbeelding));
            teller++;
        }
    }

    private void setupPreferenceGebruikersnaam() {
        String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welkomsbericht), sharedPreferences.getString("example_text", "gebruiker"));
        gebruikersnaam.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**DienstAdapter.java**

```
public class DienstAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DienstAdapter.DienstViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Dienst> dienstList;
    private List<Dienst> dienstListFiltered;
    private final ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    dienstListFiltered = dienstList;
                } else {
                    List<Dienst> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Dienst row : dienstList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getNaam().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getBeschrijving().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    dienstListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = dienstListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                dienstListFiltered = (ArrayList<Dienst>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface  ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(String url, String naam);
    }

    DienstAdapter(Context mContext, List<Dienst> dienstList, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.dienstList = dienstList;
        this.dienstListFiltered = dienstList;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public DienstViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        return new DienstViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DienstViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Dienst dienst = dienstList.get(position);

        holder.tv_naam.setText(dienst.getNaam());
        holder.tv_beschrijving.setText(dienst.getBeschrijving());
        holder.tv_categorie.setText(String.valueOf(dienst.getCategorie()));
        holder.tv_prijs.setText(String.valueOf(dienst.getPrice()));
        if (dienst.getPrice() != 0)
            holder.tv_prijs.setText(String.format("€ %.2f", dienst.getPrice()));
        else
            holder.tv_prijs.setText("");
        Glide.with(mContext).load(dienst.getAfbeelding()).into(holder.iv_afbeelding);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dienstList.size();
    }

    public class DienstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView iv_afbeelding;
        TextView tv_naam, tv_beschrijving, tv_categorie, tv_prijs;

        DienstViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            iv_afbeelding = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_afbeelding);
            tv_naam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_naam);
            tv_beschrijving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_beschrijving);
            tv_categorie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_categorie);
            tv_prijs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prijs);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            String url = dienstList.get(clickedPosition).getAfbeelding().replace(".png", ".html");
            String naam = dienstList.get(clickedPosition).getNaam();
            mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(url, naam);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `getItemCount()` and `onBindViewHolder()` should use the filtered list `dienstListFiltered`.

And You forgot to update the count of the `FilterResults`.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            // Filter data ...
            // ...

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = dienstListFiltered;
            filterResults.count = dienstListFiltered.size();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            dienstListFiltered = (ArrayList<Dienst>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

See: [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Comment: Omg thank you so much! I wasn't sure anyone was going to reply, but you replied so quickly and it worked! You are awesome!

Answer (score -2):

Can you add

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

immediately after

```
filteredList.add(row);
```

?

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, but @nhoxbypass already came up with the right solution :)