# Searchable spinner not working

Tags: android

I have a spinner with search functionality. The spinner has items like "hello-there".ie; A name followed by a hyphen and then another name. The spinner search is working fine if we search for the keyword left of the hyphen. But it will show empty if we search the keyword right of the hyphen. Is there any library that fulfills my requirement? Or how to implement this?
Iam currently using this library **com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1**

Comment: You should use AutocompleteTextview instead of Searchable spinner

Comment: @NiravJoshi bro will it solve the hyphen text isue?

Comment: yes it will solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the filter used in this library is the default filter of ArrayAdapter class.

Your best option is to create a custom filterable adapter for the spinner data.
Take a look at this 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

to resolve your hyphen problem: the filter will look like

```
 private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

**filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)** should do the trick. However, if you want more elaborate way where the prefix should be the bigining of the left or right hyphen text. You can proceed like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        filterableString = list.get(i);
         String[] parts = filterableString.split("-")
       if(parts[0].startsWith(filterString)||parts[1].startsWith(filterString){
            nlist.add(filterableString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro.