# How do I search for objects in the Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview

I call a `Fragment` `ListView` in an activity and list the user records, and I want to do a search between those user records. Do I need a little little road show? How can I create this search feature?

Edit : I can describe my problem deeper because it can help.

Comment: Depends on how you store the data......

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce given via firabase and displayed by `ListAdapter`

Comment: @SarathKn I added the search facility to the `Activity` here, I want help with this in my `Adapter` `Fragment`.

Comment: What did you try? paste some code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter items based on a property using Filterable interface if you are using ListView. You can find the implementation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/7384780

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be better to create a Database in your app and query from it (eg : RoomDB , sqllite ).
2. Use the DB as your single source of truth to display the items on your View .
   (This is where you could run your search queries for filtering and any other requirments)
3. Use Firebase to just populate your DB when the app is loading .
   This should run in an async thread. 
   I would recommend using RxJava to better handle async functions.
4. For implementing search Feature , check below official search docs 
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/
   https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup

[image]