# Filter ListView on Text Changed Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want make simple search on my list in android application:

[app face image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrtUA.png)

this is what i wrote:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"userId", "id"}, new int[]{R.id.userId, R.id.id});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

    });

}
```

in "onTextChanged" i have error under adapter, and i adopt that is there good place i put "addTextChangedListener" or not!

Comment: check this Question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Listview Adapter with filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769257/custom-listview-adapter-with-filter-android)

Answer (score 2):

Your adapter implements with Filterable and add bellow code in your adapter

```
 //this method is for fillter list
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //filter have null value than return main list
    if (userFilter == null)
        userFilter = new UserFilter(this, mValues);
    return userFilter;
}

private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private final List<DataModel> originalList;
    private final List<DataModel> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(RecyclerViewAdapter adapter, List<DataModel> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        //first clear filter list
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint.length() == 0) {
            //when Enterd no any string than all list add in filtered list
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);
        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (final DataModel user : originalList) {
                //check all list item with enterd string
                if (user.getText().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    //add match item in list
                    filteredList.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //when publish result first clear list
        adapter.mFilteredList.clear();
        //add all result value in list
        adapter.mFilteredList.addAll((ArrayList<DataModel>) results.values);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and add below code in your activity

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: `SimpleAdapter` already implements `Filterable`. How does this answer solve the OP's issue?