# Searching a ListView does not work - why?

Tags: android, search, android-listview, android-dialog

Hi I have a listView in a Dialog, and I have setup a custom adapter for the Dialog.

I lookup up and I setup the addTextChangedListener but does not seem to work.

I just want to search through the list and refresh the list when the user types in the Edit text

Any idea where I am getting it wrong please

Here is my code

```
private void showCompaniesDialog(List<Company> companies) {
    if(companies != null) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        // dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_company_listview);

        Button btndialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btndialog);
        btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.company_list_item, R.id.tv, companies);
        CompanyAdapter companyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(getActivity(), 0, companies);
        listView.setAdapter(companyAdapter);

        //HERE I SET THE TEXT FILTER ENABLED
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //textView.setText("You have clicked : " + companies[position]);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //HERE I ADD CHANGED LISTENER
        EditText etSearch = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //companyAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                companyAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Here is the custom adapter for the company

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Company>{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<Company> lCompany;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CompanyAdapter (Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, List<Company> lCompany){
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, lCompany);
        try{
            this.activity = activity;
            this.lCompany = lCompany;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return lCompany.size();
    }

    public Company getItem (Company position){
        return position;
    }

    public  long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder {
        public TextView display_name;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.display_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);


                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
            holder.display_name.setText(lCompany.get(position).getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/5909412

Comment: You're keeping your own `List` separate from the one `ArrayAdapter` maintains internally, and filters on. Simply remove your `private List<Company> lCompany;` field, and the overrides that are using it, and use `getItem(position)` in place of `lCompany.get(position)` in `getView()`. Then just make sure that your `Company` class has a `toString()` override that returns `getName()` – or its corresponding field – and `ArrayAdapter`'s built-in `Filter` will work for you.

Comment: @MikeM. I tried that, and when I type something in the EditText, it empties the list and does not filter. When you said override toString. In the Company class I have @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
It is already returning a String so should I be doing anything else here?
Another point, when I type something it empties the list and when I delete the text I have typed the list is back. Any ideas what might be happening

Comment: You have to specifically override the `toString()` method; `@Override public String toString() { return name; }`. In fact, you don't need a custom `Adapter` at all, if the only thing you're doing is setting a `TextView`'s text. Add that `toString()` override to `Company`, then `ArrayAdapter<Company> companyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.company_list_item, R.id.tvCompanyName, companies);`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Filterable` interface to your Adapter.

You can add following piece of code to your adapter

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List < String > list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList < String > nlist = new ArrayList < String > (count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList < String > ) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to change it as per your requirement

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` already implements `Filterable`, and provides its own `Filter`. This isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I implement this using a SearchView paired with a ListView.  The SearchView has some built in methods that fire when text is changed or Search is clicked, which you can override to set the filter in the ListView.

MyActivity.java

```
        // Setup the ListView
        // breedListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.breedListView);

        // My 'Activity' is actually a ListFragment so getListView() is how it is done
        breedListView = getListView();
        breedListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        breedListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Setup the searchView
        searchView = (SearchView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);                    
        setupSearchView();

        // Set some default properties
        private void setupSearchView() {
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
        }

        // Reset the filter as the user types
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                breedListView.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                breedListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Reset the filter when Search is pressed
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                breedListView.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                breedListView.setFilterText(query.toString());
            }
            return false;
        }


        // After getting/refreshing the list, do this to reapply the query to the new list
        CharSequence suggestWord = searchView.getQuery();
        searchView.setQuery(suggestWord, true);
```

MyActivity.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </SearchView>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">     
                    <ListView
                      android:id="@android:id/list"
                      android:layout_weight="0.1"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listIndex"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
            </LinearLayout> 
        </LinearLayout>
```