# filter() method is not working properly with my listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Whenever I search a name from my EditText, it filters out the names correctly but it always displays the first list item no matter what. For example, if John is the first list item and i search for Mary (who does exist in the list view) it will still show John but the rest of the items will go away. So it looks like the filtering is working but the list item is not updating accordingly.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private ArrayList<Contact> items; 
    private Context adapterContext; 

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);
        adapterContext = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        try{
            Contact contact = items.get(position);

            if(v == null) { //if there isn't an existing view to be reused, the LayoutInflater service is called to instantiate the list_item layout previously used
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) adapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textContactName);
            TextView contactNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textPhoneNumber);
            TextView contactCell = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCellNumber);
            TextView contactStreetAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textStreetAddress);
            TextView contactCityStateZip = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCityStateZip);
            Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteContact);
            ImageView starBFF = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageBFFStar);
            ImageView starBBFF = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageBBFFStar);
            contactName.setText(contact.getContactName());
            contactNumber.setText("Home: " + contact.getPhoneNumber());
            contactCell.setText("Cell: " + contact.getCellNumber());
            contactStreetAddress.setText(contact.getStreetAddress());
            contactCityStateZip.setText(contact.getCity() + ", " + contact.getState() + " " + contact.getZipCode());
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
'''

The next code is the filtering
'''
private void initSearch(){
    //SEARCHBAR
    EditText filter = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            (ContactListActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
'''
```

Comment: Working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/2711811 . Also seems like we'd need to see your filter implemenation.

Answer (score 1):

it is my code you can try it

```
public class brandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<brandAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<BrandModel> brandModelList;
    Context context;
    chooseBrand choose;
    private java.util.List<BrandModel> brand_filter;

    public void setChooseBrand(brandAdapter.chooseBrand chooseBrandr) {
        this.choose = chooseBrandr;
    }

    public brandAdapter(List<BrandModel> brandModels , brandAdapter.chooseBrand chooseBrandr, Context context) {
        brandModelList = brandModels;
        this.context = context;
        this.choose = chooseBrandr;
        brand_filter = brandModelList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.brand_item, parent, false);

        return new brandAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final BrandModel brandModel = brand_filter.get(position);
        holder.brandName.setText(brandModel.getBrandName());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                choose.getBrand(String.valueOf(brandModel.getId()), brandModel.getBrandName());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return brand_filter.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    brand_filter = brandModelList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<BrandModel> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (BrandModel row : brandModelList) {


                        if (row.getBrandName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filtered.add(row);

                        }
                    }

                    brand_filter = filtered;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = brand_filter;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                brand_filter = (ArrayList<BrandModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView brandName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            brandName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);

        }
    }

    public interface chooseBrand {
        void getBrand(String id, String name);
    }

}
```

I hope it will work with you