# SearchVIew: empty suggestion list

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I am newbie..
I need your help with suggestion for SearchView. Data from maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode recived and parced. Everything looks ok. But why there is no text in suggestions? Please help me understand whats wrong...

[image: screenshot]

JsonParser class:

```
public class JsonParser {

public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=(JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results");
        List<HashMap<String,String>> places = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int counter=0; counter<jsonArray.length(); counter++) {
            HashMap  hm=new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("id", String.valueOf(counter));
            hm.put("description",jsonArray.getJSONObject(counter).getString("formatted_address"));
            hm.put("lat",jsonArray.getJSONObject(counter).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat"));
            hm.put("lng", jsonArray.getJSONObject(counter).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng"));
            places.add(hm);
        }
        return places;
    }
    catch (JSONException jE) {
        jE.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

PlaceProvider class:

```
public class PlaceProvider extends ContentProvider {
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.gvozditskiy.photospots.PlaceProvider";

public static final Uri SEARCH_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/search");

public static final Uri DETAILS_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTHORITY+"/details");

private static final int SEARCH = 1;
private static final int SUGGESTIONS = 2;
private static final int DETAILS = 3;

private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

    UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    // URI for "Go" button
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "search", SEARCH );

    // URI for suggestions in Search Dialog
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,SUGGESTIONS);

    // URI for Details
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "details",DETAILS);

    return uriMatcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    return false;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String s, String[] strings1, String s1) {
    String url="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+strings1[0].replace(" ","+")
            .replace(",","+");
    Cursor c=null;
    JsonParser jsonParser=new JsonParser();
    String jSonString;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    MatrixCursor matrixCursor;
    switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH:
            matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"description","lat","lng"});
            try {
                jSonString=loadFromNetwork(url);
                list=jsonParser.parse(new JSONObject(jSonString));
                for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap=list.get(i);
                    matrixCursor.addRow(new String[] {hashMap.get("description"),hashMap.get("lat"), hashMap.get("lng")});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            c=matrixCursor;
            break;

        case SUGGESTIONS:
            matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA});
            try {
                jSonString=loadFromNetwork(url);
                list=jsonParser.parse(new JSONObject(jSonString));
                for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap=list.get(i);
                    matrixCursor.addRow(new String[] {Integer.toString(i) ,hashMap.get("description")});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            c=matrixCursor;
            break;

        case DETAILS:
            matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"description","lat","lng"});
            try {
                jSonString=loadFromNetwork(url);
                list=jsonParser.parse(new JSONObject(jSonString));
                for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap=list.get(i);
                    matrixCursor.addRow(new String[] {hashMap.get("description"),hashMap.get("lat"), hashMap.get("lng")});
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            c=matrixCursor;
            break;
    }
    return c;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}

private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    String str ="";
    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        str = readIt(stream);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
    return str;
}


private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
}

private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    int d;
    while ( (d = rd.read()) !=-1) {
        stringBuilder.append((char)d);
    }
    return new String(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

MainActivity (just part that works with searching):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.materialBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        setupMenuDrawer();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fabHide();
        spotList = new ArrayList<Spot>();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        isCameraSetted = false;
        spotMarker = null;
        doUpdate=true;
        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }

private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
                doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
                getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void doSearch(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
    }

    private void getPlace(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader cLoader = null;
        if(id==0)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.SEARCH_URI, null, null, new String[]{ args.getString("query") }, null);
        else if(id==1)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI, null, null, new String[]{ args.getString("query") }, null);
        return cLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        LatLng placePos;
        data.moveToFirst();
        placePos = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data.getString(1)), Double.parseDouble(data.getString(2)));
        setCamera(sMap, false, placePos);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

}
}
```

searchable.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.gvozditskiy.photospots.PlaceProvider"
        android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
        android:searchSuggestThreshold="2" >

    </searchable>
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/pointslist_main_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/drawer_item_spots"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search_main_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You need to set an adapter on your SearchView, and refresh the values within the adapter once you have data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786179/searchview-filtering-and-set-suggestions

Comment: @SebastianRoth i tried to make like in sample [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/). As i understand it is another way (am i wrong?). Now i'm intersted in finding my mistake. Then i'll try to realize solution in your link.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by replacing:

in PlaceProvider class:

```
 case SUGGESTIONS:
        matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA});
```

to

```
case SUGGESTIONS:
            matrixCursor=new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id",SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1});
```

in MainActivity class:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
            doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)){
        doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
        getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
    }
}
```