# Adapter is not displaying data, only after search

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, android-listview

Thanks for your time in advance. I'm new to android and I'd like to learn more. I have a code that is displaying data from sql only after search is clicked and I don't know how can I make it display all the data from sql with let's say alfabetical order at first and later on if search is used it will display data matching to search request.

```
public class EmployeeList extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Comment: remove sql where clause and call code in search method to show all the records. like in: "SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee". and append "order by firstName" to sort accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I want them both to work in the same time, displaying all the record and if user hits search giving the results he was searching for, is it possible on one screen on simply easier make on two different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see you are using onClick in XML layout , right?
any ways, no problem.

add new method `populateList()` as following

```
public void populateList(boolean useWhere) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    if(useWhere){
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
    }else{
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee");
    }
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.employee_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

change `search()` as following:

```
public void search(View view){
    populateList(true);
}
```

add a call `populateList(false);` to `onCreate()` of the activity.

so oncreate activity, will call search to execuste without `WHERE` and when c alled from button click, it will execute the WHERE sql

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        populateList(false);
}
```

Comment: that's the xml. no onCLick 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4px"> 

 <include android:id="@+id/search" layout="@layout/search" />

 <ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_below="@id/search"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
thanks a lot.

Comment: @Peter ignore the onClick issue, just try this sol and tell what you got... though i still doubt it's exist, maybe in `@layout/search` as it's included in your XML `<include android...`