# Android Listview searching is not working properly

Tags: android, search, android-listview, android-filter, android-filterable

Kindly help me in my code, It doesn't search perfect all other values remain on their position except the search able string.

Here is the code of filterable class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Interpolator.Result;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Filter;
    import android.widget.Filterable;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class ListViewAdapter_claimlist extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    Activity context;
    String claimid[];
    String ref[];
    String policy[];
    String natureofloss[];
    String registration[];
    String status[];

    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

     private List<String>originalData = null;
     private List<String>filteredData = null;

     private List<String>claimidFilter = null;
     private List<String>refFilter = null;
     private List<String>nautreoflossfilter = null;
     private List<String>registrationFilter = null;
     private List<String>statusFilter = null;

     ArrayList<abc> alldata = new ArrayList<abc>();


    public ListViewAdapter_claimlist(Activity context, String[] claimid, String[] ref,String[] policy, String[] natureofloss,String[] registration, String[] status) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.claimid = claimid;
        this.ref = ref;
        this.policy = policy;
        this.natureofloss = natureofloss;
        this.registration = registration;
        this.status = status;

        this.filteredData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.policy));
        this.originalData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.policy));

        this.claimidFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.claimid));
        this.refFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.ref));
        this.nautreoflossfilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.natureofloss));
        this.registrationFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.registration));
        this.statusFilter = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(this.status));

        for(int i = 0; i<this.claimid.length; i++)
        {
            abc a = new abc();
            a.setClaimid(claimid[i]);
            a.setRef(ref[i]);
            a.setPolicy(policy[i]);
            a.setNatureofLoss(natureofloss[i]);
            a.setRegistration(registration[i]);
            a.setStatus(status[i]);
            alldata.add(a);
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView cliamid;
        TextView ref;
        TextView policy;
        TextView natureofloss;
        TextView registration;
        TextView status;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowitem_cliamlist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.cliamid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_claims);
            holder.ref = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_referencepolicy);
            holder.policy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_policyNo);
            holder.natureofloss = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_natureoflos);
            holder.registration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_registration);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_claimstatus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        abc aa = alldata.get(position);
        holder.cliamid.setText(aa.getClaimid());
        holder.ref.setText(aa.getRef());
        holder.policy.setText(filteredData.get(position));
        holder.natureofloss.setText(aa.getNatureofloss());
        holder.registration.setText(aa.getRegistration());
        holder.status.setText(aa.getStatus());

    return convertView;

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         public Filter getFilter() {
                return mFilter;
            }

            private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                    final List<String> list = originalData;

                    int count = list.size();
                    final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                    String filterableString ;

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        filterableString = list.get(i);

                        if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                            nlist.add(filterableString);


                        }
                    }

                    results.values = nlist;
                    results.count = nlist.size();


                    return results;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

            public class abc
            {
                String claimid;
                String ref;
                String policy;
                String natureofloss;
                String registration;
                String status;

                 public void setClaimid(String claimid)
                 { 
                     this.claimid = claimid;
                 }
                 public void setRef(String ref)
                 {
                     this.ref = ref;
                 }
                 public void setPolicy(String policy)
                 {
                     this.policy = policy;
                 }
                 public void setNatureofLoss(String natureofloss)
                 {
                     this.natureofloss = natureofloss;
                 }
                 public void setRegistration(String registration)
                 {
                     this.registration = registration; 
                 }
                 public void setStatus(String status)
                 {
                     this.status = status; 
                 }

                 public String getClaimid()
                 {
                     String claimid = this.claimid;
                     return claimid;
                 }
                 public String getRef()
                 {

                     String ref = this.ref;
                     return ref;
                 }
                 public String getPolicy()
                 {

                     String Policy = this.policy;
                     return Policy;
                 }
                 public String getNatureofloss()
                 {

                     String Natureofloss = this.natureofloss;
                     return Natureofloss;
                 }
                 public String getRegistration()
                 {

                     String Registration = this.registration;
                     return Registration;
                 }
                 public String getStatus()
                 {

                     String Status = this.status;
                     return Status;
                 }

            }

    }
```

Edit Text Event Handler

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClaimList.this.lviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Before Search

[image]

When Search by Police No(policy# in code)

[image]

Thank in Advance :)

Comment: where do you get your data from?  sqlite db?

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Comment: I am getting my data from 'WebService' and sending from main class through bunch of Arrays

Comment: store the data to sqlite db, it will simplify your code to 1/3 of what you have now

Comment: lots of things are there i can't change to sqlite brother.... well Haresh chhelana i can't perfectly implement that on my code. please help me another way

Answer (score 0):

You can choose another trick for this, set an textWatcher on the edit text where you are entering the search text.

```
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = searchText.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                lviewAdapter.filter(text);

            }
        });
```

put a filter method in Adapter class

```
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        temp.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            temp.addAll(list_original);
        } else {
            for (Abc abc: list_original) {
                 // if you want to search via policy
                if (abc.getPolicy().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    temp.add(abc);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And create two Abc type arraylists one is temp and one is original, always pass data to the listview in getview method from temp list,  so that you can make changes in temp, not the original one. In above case the temp list cleared first and run a loop to check that search text in original list if matches then add that object to temp list, and called notifyDataSetChanged.. Voila

Comment: bro i am new in android i couldn't make changes that you said ... can you check my code on skyp or team viewer?