# CustomListAdapter returning only 1st result

Tags: java, android

I have a simple search app that searches through a list of countries. It worked  properly when its just a simple list view with just Strings but now I have had to make a custom list adapter and add the flags to the list, my search(Filter) no longer works as it always returns the same result (The 1st result) and a few others, none related to the search I have provided.

SearchActivity

```
public class SearchResults extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = SearchResults.class.getSimpleName();

private ListView list;
private TextView emptyResultsTextView;

String[] listOfText = {
        "afghanistan",
        "albania",
        "algeria",
        "andorra",
        "angola",
        "antigua_and_barbuda",
        "armenia",
        "aruba",
        "australia",
        "austria",
        "azerbaijan",
        "bahamas_the",
        "bahrain",
        "bangladesh",
        "barbados"
};

Integer[] listImages = {
        R.mipmap.afghanistan,
        R.mipmap.albania,
        R.mipmap.algeria,
        R.mipmap.andorra,
        R.mipmap.angola,
        R.mipmap.antigua_and_barbuda,
        R.mipmap.armenia,
        R.mipmap.aruba,
        R.mipmap.australia,
        R.mipmap.austria,
        R.mipmap.azerbaijan,
        R.mipmap.bahamas_the,
        R.mipmap.bahrain,
        R.mipmap.bangladesh,
        R.mipmap.barbados
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, listOfText, listImages);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String searchPhrase = intent.getExtras().getString("search");
    Log.i(TAG, "Search phrase is " + searchPhrase);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchResultsListView);
    emptyResultsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyResultsSearch);
    emptyResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        adapter.getFilter().filter(searchPhrase, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    emptyResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emptyResultsTextView.setText(R.string.no_results);
                }
            }
        });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = listOfText[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity activity;
private final String[] countryName;
private final Integer[] imgId;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, String[] countryName, Integer[] imgId){
    super(activity, R.layout.search_results_row_list, countryName);

    this.activity = activity;
    this.countryName = countryName;
    this.imgId = imgId;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_results_row_list, null, false);


    TextView txtCountry = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.country_text);
    ImageView imageViewCountry = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.country_flag);

    txtCountry.setText(countryName[position]);
    imageViewCountry.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
    return rowView;

}

}
```

how can I have it search just the text part i.e. the country name and return that? Am I doing the search correctly by using:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(searchPhrase, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    emptyResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emptyResultsTextView.setText(R.string.no_results);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: where is the logic to search value and display it ??

Comment: This worked when I had it searching a list of Strings. Could you maybe point me to something that I can get an understand of the logic etc that you are talking about?

Comment: What is the purpose of that count == 0 condition there?

Comment: if the results are empty then display "No Results found"

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter/23422665#23422665

Comment: That worked wonders @HareshChhelana

Comment: @x10sion,Glad to help you,If my ans is useful to you then you can appreciate by up vote my ans.