# Searchview in custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a custom 'ArrayAdapter' in a 'ListView', my problem is using a menu 'SearchView'. It's not working properly. I don´t know if the problem is searching or showing the results, because nothing appears. And, if possible, I wnat to show a custom list of results. Thanks!

Fragment with the adapter

```
 ArrayList<Favoritos> favorites;
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    favorites = new ArrayList<Favoritos>();
    favorites.add(new Favorites("Title", "addres", 5, false, 7, 22, 4.5f));
    favorites.add(new Favorites("Title", "addres", 3.5 , true, 7, 22, 3.0f));
    favorites.add(new Favorites("Title", "addres", 2, false, 7, 22, 4.0f));
    favorites.add(new Favorites("Titleo", "addres", 4.5, true, 7, 22, 5.0f));

    FavoritesAdapter adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(), favorites);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }


 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String string) {
    search(string);
    return true;
}

//This is the search method
public void search(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.trim().equals("")) {
        cleanSearch(); //In this method I just "reset" the adapter when the user "give up"
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<Favoritos> estacionamentosEncontrados = new ArrayList<Favoritos>(favoritos);

    for (int i = estacionamentosEncontrados.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Favoritos estacionamento = estacionamentosEncontrados.get(i);
        Favoritos nenhumResultado = new Favoritos("Nenhum resultado encontrado");
        if (!estacionamento.mIndicacao.toUpperCase().contains(s.toUpperCase())) {
            estacionamentosEncontrados.remove(estacionamento);
        } else {
            estacionamentosEncontrados.add(nenhumResultado);
        }
    }

    adapter = new EncontradosAdapter(getActivity(), estacionamentosEncontrados);
    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Favorites.java

```
   public String mIndicacao;
   public String mEndereco;
   private double mPreco;
   public boolean mDisponibilidade;
   private double mHoraAbre;
   private double mHoraFecha;
   private float mAvaliacao;

   public Favoritos(){

   }

  public Favoritos(String indicacao, String endereco, double preco, boolean disponibilidade, double horaAbre, double horaFecha, float avaliacao){
    mIndicacao = indicacao;
    mEndereco = endereco;
    mPreco = preco;
    mDisponibilidade = disponibilidade;
    mHoraAbre = horaAbre;
    mHoraFecha = horaFecha;
    mAvaliacao = avaliacao;
}

//Getters and Setters
```

And the custom Adapter

```
public class FavoritesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Favorites> {


public FavoritesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Favorites> favorites){
    super(context, 0, favoritos);
}

public static class ItemViewHolder{
    TextView indicadorTextView;
    TextView enderecoTextView;
    TextView precoTextView;
    TextView horaAbreTextView;
    TextView horaFechaTextView;
    RatingBar notaEstacionamento;
    ImageView disponivelImg;
    TextView disponivelTextView;
    ImageView esconderView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View view){
        indicadorTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indicador);
        enderecoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        precoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.precoValor);
        horaAbreTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(horaAbre);
        horaFechaTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(horaFecha);
        notaEstacionamento = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        disponivelImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_disponibilidade);
        disponivelTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disponivel);
        esconderView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.esconder_view_btn);

    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.favorites_item, parent, false);
    }

    Favorites currentFavorito = getItem(position);

    final ItemViewHolder holder;

    if(listItemView.getTag() == null){
        holder = new ItemViewHolder(listItemView);
        listItemView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ItemViewHolder) listItemView.getTag();
    }

    if(currentFavorito.getDisponibilidade()){
        holder.disponivelTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getIndicacao());
    } else {
        holder.disponivelTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getIndicacao());
    }
    holder.indicadorTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getIndicacao());
    holder.enderecoTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getEndereco());
    holder.precoTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getPreco());
    holder.horaAbreTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getHoraAbre());
    holder.horaFechaTextView.setText(currentFavorito.getHoraFecha());
    holder.notaEstacionamento.setRating(currentFavorito.getAvaliacao());


    if(currentFavorito.getDisponibilidade()){
        holder.disponivelImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ir_img);
        holder.disponivelTextView.setText(R.string.aberto);
        holder.disponivelTextView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
    } else {
        holder.disponivelImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.fechado_img);
        holder.disponivelTextView.setText(R.string.fechado);
        holder.disponivelTextView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.vermelho));        }

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: why are you not creating your own serchview in the List

Comment: I don't know, is my first project. I thought this was the best way to do it. How can I create this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23422665/8648705

Comment: I tried this before. I got problems with the Filter and positioning the search icon

Comment: You can try this answer. it is work for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/6250392

Comment: guys, I´m sorry for have´nt answered you. I got it just declaring the favorites variable as global, and passing it as a parameter when creating a serch method. I'll edit the questions for you (and who has problem with it too) to see

Answer (score 0):

Step : 1 Create option menu in fragment for searchview like

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        //menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.ticket_fragment_search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem actionSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

       SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(actionSearch);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchEditText.setSingleLine(true);
        searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_search_here));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //apply Filter
                adapter.setFilter(newText)
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG, "search open");
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                Log.e(TAG, "search close");
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Step 2 : create function for filter or search in adapter

```
public void setFilter(String str) {
        aList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (aListTemp.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < aListTemp.size(); i++) {
                if (aListTemp.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
                        ) {

                    aList.add(aListTemp.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```