# SearchView that filters complex data (object and custom layout)

Tags: android, filter, kotlin, searchview

I have my adapter that extend a class **MatchableArrayAdapter** that i've found on the internet.

The class allows me to have a complex layout for my list view (layout that is not only Textview, but several layout and textViews).

I have this complex layout because I'm using object with several data inside it (so I can on the same item display a name, an ID...)

So i'm passing an **ArrayList of object** from my fragment to my adapter.

***What I want is this :***

I want to **add a searchView** that will *filter* on *any of the object* *properties* (filter on ID, name, location...)

Any idea how to do that ? I've found that I need to use **Filterable** but I don't understand why...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView In ListView having a custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422072/searchview-in-listview-having-a-custom-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

so.. it's easier to do the filtering manually with an EditText.

but! if you still want to do it with a Filter and a SearchView, it goes like this:

1. you need to extend the Filter class, something like this:

   ```
   private class MyFilter extends Filter {

       @Override
       protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
           final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

           if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
               final ArrayList<MyObject> list;
               synchronized (adapter) {
                   list = new ArrayList<>(allObjects);
               }
               results.values = list;
               results.count = list.size();
           } else {
               final String prefixString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

               final ArrayList<MyObject> values;
               synchronized (adapter) {
                   values = new ArrayList<>(allObjects);
               }

               final int count = values.size();
               final ArrayList<MyObject> newValues = new ArrayList<>();

               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   final MyObject value = values.get(i);
                   final String valueText = value.firstName.toLowerCase() + " " + value.lastName.toLowerCase();
                   Log.i("search", valueText);
                   if (valueText.contains(prefixString)) {
                       newValues.add(value);
                       Log.i("search", "in");
                   }
               }
               results.values = newValues;
               results.count = newValues.size();
           }
           return results;
       }

       @Override
       protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
           adapter.students = (List<MyObject>) results.values;
           if (results.count > 0) {
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           } else {
               adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

notice i used firstname and lastname as fields of MyObject, and you should change that to the values you're searching for.

2. you need to override the method getFilter in your adapter:

   ```
   @Override
   public Filter getFilter(){
       return new MyFilter();
   }
   ```
3. setup the searchView query listener:

   ```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

hope that helps someone,

cheers